# Entropy problem

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

> A tank is divided into two equal chambers by an internal diaphragm. One chamber contains methane at a pressure of $\pu{500 bar}$ and a temperature of $\pu{20 °C},$ and the other chamber is evacuated. Suddenly, the diaphragm bursts. Compute the final temperature and pressure of the gas in the tank after sufficient time has passed for equilibrium to be attained. Assume that there is no heat transfer between the tank and the gas and that methane obeys the van der Waals equation of state. Data: $C_p = \pu{35.56 J mol^-1 K^-1}$

Comment: You should post your thoughts on how to solve this. This is not a HWK solving site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given the initial and final volumes, the amount of gas, and the initial temperature. The expansion is adiabatic and free so no heat is exchanged and no work is done, meaning that $\Delta U = 0$. If it were an ideal gas, this would mean that the temperature is unchanged and that the final pressure is given by Boyle's law. However it is a van der Waals gas. We therefore make use of the thermodynamic equation of state:
$$dU = \left[ T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V - P  \right]dV + C_V dT $$
For the vdW gas
$$\left[ T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V - P  \right] =\frac{a}{V_m^2} $$
so that
$$\Delta U = 0 = a\left( \frac{1}{V_{m,ini}}-\frac{1}{V_{m,fin}} \right) + C_V \Delta T$$
or
$$T_{fin} = T_{ini} + \frac{a}{C_V}\left( \frac{1}{V_{m,fin}}-\frac{1}{V_{m,ini}} \right) $$
From this last expression you can determine the final T, and knowing the final volume you can compute the final pressure using the vdW EOS.

Comment: Actually, we are given the density or molar volume of the gas, but the answer is the same.

Comment: To integrate the temperature term, one must first verify that Cv is not a function of molar volume for a VDW gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller Good point, I overlooked that and assumed it was constant.